# Copying a char array to the char array field of a struct in an array of the struct?

Tags: c

Pardon me if the question is too confusing!

I have the following structs:

```
struct msg { 
    char data[20];
}

struct pkt {
   int seqnum;
   int acknum;
   int checksum;
   char payload[20];
};
```

I have the following array of struct:

```
struct msg buffer[1000];
```

Now, I am doing the following:

```
void A_output(struct msg message)
{
    //printf("Message in A: %s\n", message.data);
    if(inTransit == 0) {
        if(hasBuffer > 0) {
            printf("%s\n", "Sending from buffer...");
            memset(&currentpkt_A->payload, '\0', 20);

            strncpy(currentpkt_A->payload, buffer[buffCount].data, 20);
            currentpkt_A->seqnum = seq_A;
            setChecksum(currentpkt_A);
            printf("Checksum from A: %d\n", currentpkt_A->checksum);
            printf("Payload from A: %s\n", currentpkt_A->payload);
            tolayer3(0, *currentpkt_A);
            inTransit = 1;

            starttimer(0, increment);

            printf("%s\n", "Adding to buffer when sending directly...");
            strncpy(buffer[hasBuffer].data, message.data, 20);
            hasBuffer++;
            buffCount++;
        }
        else {
            printf("Sending directly...\n");
            memset(&currentpkt_A->payload, '\0', 20);

            strncpy(currentpkt_A->payload, message.data, 20);
            currentpkt_A->seqnum = seq_A;
            setChecksum(currentpkt_A);
            printf("Checksum from A: %d\n", currentpkt_A->checksum);
            printf("Payload from A: %s\n", currentpkt_A->payload);
            tolayer3(0, *currentpkt_A);

            starttimer(0, increment);

            inTransit = 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("%s\n", "Adding to buffer when in transit...");
        strncpy(buffer[hasBuffer].data, message.data, 20);
        hasBuffer++;
    }
    printf("Buffer now has: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i<hasBuffer; i++)
        printf("%s\n", buffer[i].data);
}
```

The problem is, when I am adding to the buffer and printing it out I can see the following:

On the first addition buffer is:

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

On the second addition buffer is:

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

On the third addition buffer is:

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccc

bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccc

cccccccccccccccccccc

That is, it's getting added to the end of every cell of the array and then the new cell. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: There is no space for NUL in there.

Comment: Maybe your source strings do not have a null terminator in the first 20 characters. The strncpy function does not add one in that case, so you would read off the end of your buffers

Comment: What exactly do you expect it to do?

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve